# cakephp join from sorted and limited row

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I have a working SQL query i want to figure out what would be the CakePHP query builder equivalent to work the exact same way?

```
SELECT customers.*, customer_reps.created FROM customers
LEFT JOIN customer_reps ON customer_reps.id =
    (
    SELECT id FROM customer_reps WHERE customer_id = customers.id
    ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE created >= 1475298000
AND created <= 1476217836
AND agents_id = 4
```

So essentially i am selecting all columns from "customers" and then i want only the "created" timestamp field of the FIRST "customer_reps" table for matching customer.

Documentation on CakePHP doesn't seem to explain how to do the select within select for sorting as this. I tried using the "hasMany" relational stuff but i was not able to find how to just get the "first" customer_reps entry to add to the main query for use in WHERE clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code as a starting point you just need to group it by CustomerRep.customer_id because the order is already ascending if you're customer_reps table id is auto incremented already

```
    $this->Customer->find('all', array(
        'fields' => arrray(
            'Customer.*',
            'CustomerRep.created'
            ),
        'joins' => array(
             array(
                 'type' => 'LEFT',
                 'table' => 'customer_reps',
                 'alias' => 'CustomerRep',
                 'conditions' => 'Customer.id = CustomerRep.customer_id'
                )
            )
        'conditions' => array(
            'Customer.created >=' => '1475298000',
            'Customer.created <=' => '1476217836',
            'Customer.agentds_id' => 4
            ),
        'group' => 'CustomerRep.customer_id'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with cakephp query builder? then if yes you should understand this flow

Step 1: `SELECT customers.*, customer_reps.created FROM customers` equivalent in cakephp is

```
$this->Customer->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Customer.*',
        'CustomerReply.created'
    )
);
```

Note: `CustomerReply.created` is from join table of `customer_reps` which I just alias `CustomerReply`

Step 2: `LEFT JOIN customer_reps ON customer_reps.id =
    (
    SELECT id FROM customer_reps WHERE customer_id = customers.id
    ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
    )` equivalent in cakephp is

```
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'customer_reps',
        'type' => 'left',
        'alias' => 'CustomerReply',
        'conditions' => array(
            'CustomerReply.id = (SELECT id FROM customer_reps WHERE customer_id = Customer.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)'
        )
    ))
```

Step 3: `WHERE created >= 1475298000
        AND created <= 1476217836
        AND agents_id = 4` equivalent in cakephp is

```
    'conditions' => array(
            'Customer.created >=' => 1475298000,
            'Customer.created <=' => 1476217836,
            'Customer.agents_id' => 4
            )
        );
```

so your cakephp query builder would be like this

```
$query = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Customer.*',
        'CustomerReply.created'
        ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'customer_reps',
            'type' => 'left',
            'alias' => 'CustomerReply',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CustomerReply.id = (SELECT id FROM customer_reps WHERE customer_id = Customer.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)'
            )
        )),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Customer.created >=' => 1475298000,
        'Customer.created <=' => 1476217836,
        'Customer.agents_id' => 4
        )
    ));
```